# Why call to @Autowired field inside my bean returns null?

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception, autowired

I created a bean from class `Driver`. When accessing `@Autowire` field `wait` inside that bean from it's own method everything works fine, but when I call `wait` directly inside the bean with `driver.wait` I'm getting `NullPointerException`. Can someone explain why this is happening?

```
public class Driver{

    @Autowire 
    public MyWait wait;

    public void waitForIt(){
        this.wait.doStuff();
    }
}


@Component
@Lazy
public class MyWait{

    public void doStuff(){
        doingStuff();
    }
}


@Configuration
@Scope("cucumber-glue")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"utilities"})
@Lazy
public class SpringConfig {

    @Bean
    @Lazy
    public Driver getDriver() {
        return new Driver();
    }
}


@ContextConfiguration(classes = SpringConfig.class)
public Steps{

    @Autowire
    @Lazy
    Driver driver;

    public void waitForX(){
    driver.waitForIt(); <- works fine
    driver.wait.doStuff(); <- java.lang.NullPointerException on wait field
}
```

Comment: In order for the Autowiring to work, the class in which it is set, must also be instantiated through Spring, so the moment you instantiate driver with: = new Driver(); you can't Autowire it's members

Comment: Don't use field autowiring. Use a constructor.

Comment: @Stultuske I do it inside Bean method, so it should be fine.

Comment: Don't use field access. Make the field private and add a `pulbic getWait` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are accessing the `driver.wait` field using a field reference. Spring auto-wire is based on generated proxies which are applied to methods, especially when some of the beans are `@Lazy`. As per [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#spring-core):

> In addition to its role for component initialization, you can also place the `@Lazy` annotation on injection points marked with `@Autowired` or `@Inject`. In this context, it leads to the injection of a lazy-resolution proxy.

Below should work assuming that there is a corresponding `getWait()` method:

```
driver.getWait().doStuff()
```

Comment: since he instantiates driver with: new Driver(); it shouldn't.

Comment: @Stultuske  But it was done in a `@Bean` method of `@Configuraiton`class which makes `Driver` a valid bean. NPE on `driver.wait` reference which is null because `MyWait` bean is `@Lazy`. It might work if it's not `@Lazy` but field access is not something you want to debug when using `@Autowire`, just use methods.